# Passing data or parameters from one view to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

my current problem includes three classes let's say A, B and C.
Class A includes one property of an object of class B and one of class C, a string in this case.
the user should create a new object of type A in the first step without these two properties (only the other properties are asked). An incomplete object of type A (let's call it a) should be built and in the next step the user shall decide whether he wants to match this object to an existing B or a new one. After this decision, the needed property is added to a and in the third step, the second property will be added in the same way and to finish it, the object a will be saved in the database.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /A/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(A a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ViewForB", new { a = a});
        }
        return View(a);
    }
    public ActionResult ViewForB(A a)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ViewForB(B b, A a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bDb.Bs.Add(b);
            bDb.SaveChanges();
            a.propertyForB = b.title;
            return RedirectToAction("ViewForC", new {a = a});
        }
        return View(b);
    }

    public ActionResult ViewForC(A a)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ViewForC(C c, A a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            cDb.Cs.Add(c);
            cDb.SaveChanges();
            a.propertyForC = c.title;
            aDb.As.Add(a);
            aDb.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index/");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

As you can see I tried to pass an A object to every next view but when submitting in ViewForB this won't work, because I don't know how to pass it in this case.
But in ViewForB objects of type B will also be built, therefore I decided to make it in this way to verify if the inputs for B are correct or not like in the create method.

Do you know how to pass an object of type A to the last view, to complete and safe it there?

Thank you very much, any answer would be helpful.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061440/304683) helps.

Comment: @EdSF how is that relevant?

Comment: @AntP using ViewModels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to "pass" an arbitrary object from one view to another like this. When you return a `RedirectResult` you are returning an instruction to the browser to send a fresh request to the next URL - you can include simple query string parameters in this but there is no convention for serializing an arbitrary object to a set of query string parameters.

You have various options:

1. Store the information in a cookie and retrieve it in each action.
2. Return views directly from your POST actions, include hidden fields for fields that have already been populated and gradually build up a complete model.
3. Use Session or some other server-side storage mechanism (e.g. a secondary database) to save progress.

You can also pass individual properties in the redirect instead of an entire model (you can still bind back to a model in the next action). This could be used either to pass keys for a model stored in a cookie or in Session or - if you only have a few properties that you need - to just pass them all individually:

```
return RedirectToAction("ViewForC",
    new { Something = A.SomeProperty, SomethingElse = A.AnotherProperty });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found that option but I'm not sure how to use these hidden fields. ViewForB is still the same but I added this one for each property of A:
   <asp:hiddenfield id="titleField"
              value= @ViewData["title"] 
              runat="server"/>
I'm not sure how to set the value of the hidden field and after submitting, how to get it in the post method from ViewForB.

Comment: It tried for example:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewForB(B b)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string title = titleField.Value;
                cDb.Bs.Add(b);
                cDb.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ViewForC", new { varTitle = title });
            }
            return View();
        }  

But it says that titleField is unknown in the context.

Comment: What is `titleField`? What is `varTitle`? These things don't appear to exist. Not sure what you're trying to do there. It sounds like you're confused on a few different fronts and you need to do some Googling and reading up on how model binding works.

Comment: Have a look at my comment, titleField is a hiddenField, it is an example for a property of an object of type A. I didn't want to wrote all the properties I chose one for example.
varTitle is the name of a variable, it is an example for a property of an object of Type A. In the controller-method for ViewForC I could write:
public ActionResult ViewForC(string varTitle)
{ ... } .
What I'm trying to do:
I try to place a hidden field for one property of a, it's name should be "titleField". After submitting, I want to get the input of titleField to pass it to the next view.