# View use of Model and ViewModel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning about ASP.NET and working in an application and I don't seem to understand the difference between the Model and the `ViewModel`. When in a View the information you want is taken from the Model you call using `@model`. If you want to make a `dropdown list` you will display the information you get from there right? When using `@Html.Action` you call a method of the Controller where you create a `ViewModel` object with the same `{get; set}` methods and the same information as the Model. So why using this if it's the same as the Model? Or it isn't?

Probably my question doesn't make 100% sense, keep in mind I'm still new to `ASP.NET`. What I need to understand is the difference between the `Model` and the `ViewModel`.

I found this post: [ASP.NET MVC Model vs ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061440/asp-net-mvc-model-vs-viewmodel), but I need the answer to be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model vs ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061440/asp-net-mvc-model-vs-viewmodel)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have 2 models Blog and Category:

```
public class Blog
{
    public string BlogTitle{ get; set; }
    public string Body{ get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryTitle{ get; set; }
}
```

A ViewModel is a solution for showing both of these on a single view.  It is an alternative to using ViewBag, but in my opinion a much better one, because it allows you to strongly type the model properties.

In this case if you wanted to show a Blog post and list of categories you would create a view model

```
public class BlogCategoriesViewModel
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

And in your view:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.BlogCategoriesViewModel

<h1>@Model.Blog.BlogTitle</h1>

<h2>Categories</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model.Categories) 
{
    <p>item.CategoryTitle</p>
}
```

In the View the ViewModel in this case is basically a collection of 2 submodes.  A ViewModel also lets you add properties to your view which aren't directly mapped to domain entities.

Hope that helps